A homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{*}\times\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{5}^{*}$
$\text{Is the mapping f from the group} \langle\mathbb{Z}_{3}^{*}\times\mathbb{Z}_{4},\cdot\rangle$ to the group $\langle\mathbb{Z}_{5}^{*},\otimes\rangle$ a homomorphism?
$$f((x,y))=(x + y\mod 4) + 1$$

$ \text{Lets note for clarity: } A = \mathbb{Z}_{3}^{*}\times\mathbb{Z}_{4}
, B = \mathbb{Z}_{5}^{*} $
$ \text{All }(x_{1},y_{1}) , (x_{2},y_{2}) \in A: $
$$ f((x_{1},y_{1}) \cdot  (x_{2},y_{2})) = f((x_{1},y_{1})) \otimes f((x_{2},y_{2})) $$
How do I apply the mapping f(x) to this so that I can proceed with solving the equation?

Identity of $A$ is $(1,0)$ which gets mapped to the non-identity element $2$ in the co-domain; hence it is not a homomorphism.

@AnuradhaN. Thank you! But I still want to know how the mapping looks in the equation... so that I can figure the answer myself

$f((x_1,y_1).(x_2,y_2)) = f(x_1x_2, y_1 + y_2) = (x_1x_2 + y_1 +y_2) \pmod{4} + 1$, and $f(x_1, y_1) \otimes f(x_2, y_2) = ((x_1 + y_1)\pmod{4} +1).((x_2 + y_2)\pmod{4} + 1)) \pmod{5}$.

@AnuradhaN.  how did you get this $f((x_1,y_1).(x_2,y_2))=f(x_1x_2,y_1+y_2)$? I am quite puzzled as to why and how $(x_1,y_1).(x_2,y_2)$ becomes $(x_1x_2,y_1+y_2) $ ....

Because $\mathbf{Z}^{*}_3$  is a group w.r.t. multiplication, while $\mathbf{Z}_4$ is a group w.r.t. addition.  Then apply the definition of direct product of groups.

How is the "$+$" in $x+y$ even defined? Do we refer to the representatives in ${1,2}$ and ${0,1,2,3}$? If yes, please say so. Otherwise, the addition of $x$ and $y$ does not make sense. Example $(1+2)\pmod{4}\neq(4+2)\pmod{4}$, although $1$ and $4$ are the same in $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\star}$.

@ReinhardMeier From the context, it is understood, that is why I did not specify.

I cannot edit an earlier comment beyond the time limit, so it should actually be $f(x_1x_2,  y_1+y_2) = ((x_1x_2 \pmod{3}) + y_1 +y_2) \pmod{4} + 1$ (because if $x_1 = x_2 = 2$, we can run into problems if we do not reduce $\pmod{3}$).

I agree. However, the OP does not mention that something must be "reduced" before we add $x$ and $y$. We run into problems if we do not define the "$+$" operation between $\mathbb{Z}_3^{\star}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4.$ This operation is not defined in the first place. Usually the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are defined as the equivalence classes of the relation $a\sim b \Leftrightarrow \exists n\in\mathbb{Z}: a-b=pn.$ So $x+y$ (if $x=1$ and $y=2$) would be something like ${\ldots,-5,-2,1,4,\ldots}+{\ldots,-6,-2,2,4,\ldots}$ What is this even supposed to mean?

I assumed he meant the "+" operation as between ordinary integers (after first reducing $\pmod{3}$ and $\pmod{4}$) and then applying again a $\pmod{4}$ reduction which added to $1$ would give an element of $\mathbf{Z}^{*}_5$.  But perhaps the question is itself misplaced.
